# The code compiles and runs, but doesn't do anything

Tags: c, struct, task

I'm Marinnette. Newbie here! Have a problem with my uni programming assignment. I wrote a code that should work but it doesn't even starts for some reason( Can you tell me why? Also I would be veeery grateful if you'd find some mistakes in the code. To clear how it should work I'll add photos of the task [task description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq5lH.png) [file classifiers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVU6Y.png)

Here's gcc command I use in console
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLHJY.png)

You can see that it compiles but when I start it it doesn't work

The files from which I read data look like this

[`water_intake_stations.txt`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq1gc.png)

```
POH0013422  Allika_farm_(21588) Raikküla_Farmer_OÜ  Rapla   Rapla_vald  11  21  30
POH0023747  Valli_13-B_(25368)  Põlva_Agro_OÜ   Põlva   Põlva_vald  11  21  32
POH0000411  Aarna_mõis_(11115)  Põlva_Agro_OÜ   Põlva   Põlva_vald  11  21  32
POH0000412  Aarna_(11129)   Põlva_Agro_OÜ   Põlva   Põlva_vald  11  21  32
POH0023777  Lepametsa_(52572)   Folia_Agro__OÜ  Saare   Saaremaa_vald   11  21  30
POH0006475  lennujaama_puurkaev_(13324) Tallinna_Lennujaam,_Kärdla  Hiiu    Hiiumaa_vald    11  21  30
POH0001093  Värska_(11203)  OÜ_Setomaa_Haldus   Võru    Setomaa_vald    11  21  31
POH0015118  Antsla-Inno_(10733) Antsla-Inno_AS  Võru    Antsla_vald 11  21  30
POH0004094  Arkna_(10715)   HKScan_Estonia_AS   Lääne-Viru  Rakvere_vald    11  21  31
POH0000446  Arkna_(10713)   HKScan_Estonia_AS   Lääne-Viru  Rakvere_vald    11  21  30
POH0000992  Arkna_(10706)   HKScan_Estonia_AS   Lääne-Viru  Rakvere_vald    11  21  31
POH0000993  Arkna_(10705)   HKScan_Estonia_AS   Lääne-Viru  Rakvere_vald    11  21  31
POH0000991  Arkna_(19493)   HKScan_Estonia_AS   Lääne-Viru  Rakvere_vald    11  21  31
POH0000990  Arkna_(5745)    HKScan_Estonia_AS   Lääne-Viru  Rakvere_vald    11  21  31
POH0000989  Arkna_(5749)    HKScan_Estonia_AS   Lääne-Viru  Rakvere_vald    11  21  31
POH0000053  Tsirguliina_(9986)  Valga_Vesi_AS   Valga   Valga_vald  11  21  31
```

[`water_extraction.txt`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBn35.png)

```
POH0013422  2010    7   3500
POH0013422  2010    8   3500
POH0013422  2010    9   3500
POH0013422  2010    10  2500
POH0013422  2010    11  2500
POH0013422  2010    12  2500
POH0013422  2011    1   2067
POH0013422  2011    2   2067
POH0013422  2011    3   2067
POH0013422  2011    4   2067
POH0013422  2011    5   2067
POH0013422  2011    6   2067
POH0013422  2011    7   1860
POH0013422  2011    8   1860
POH0013422  2011    9   1880
POH0013422  2011    10  4800
POH0013422  2011    11  4750
POH0013422  2011    12  4750
POH0013422  2012    1   4650
POH0013422  2012    2   4650
POH0013422  2012    3   4650
POH0013422  2012    4   4766
POH0013422  2012    5   4767
POH0013422  2012    6   4767
POH0013422  2012    7   3541
POH0013422  2012    8   3539
POH0013422  2012    9   3430
POH0013422  2012    10  2911
POH0013422  2012    11  2889
POH0013422  2012    12  2908
POH0013422  2013    1   2691
POH0013422  2013    2   2663
POH0013422  2013    3   2688
POH0013422  2013    4   3150
```

The files are big. Intake stations has 3013 line and water extractions 197045 lines. Picture to just to understand how I read them.

THANK YOU

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 4
#define INTAKE 3013
#define EXTRACT 197045

typedef struct intake{
    char country[40];
    char code[40];
    int intake_type;
    int water_type;
    int purification;
} intake_t;

typedef struct extract{
    char code[40];
    int year;
    int amount;
} extract_t;


int main(void){

    
    printf("test");
    
    char *line1[MAX] = {"Water_type", "YES", "NO", "Unknown"};
    char *ground[MAX] = {"Ground_water", "0", "0", "0"};
    char *mineral[MAX] = {"Mineral_water", "0", "0", "0"};
    char *mining[MAX] = {"Mining_water", "0", "0", "0"};
    char *quarry[MAX] = {"Quarry_water", "0", "0", "0"};
    char *sea[MAX] = {"Sea_water", "0", "0", "0"};
    char *surface[MAX] = {"Surface_water", "0", "0", "0"};
    char *technical[MAX] = {"Technical_water", "0", "0", "0"};
    char *unknown[MAX] = {"Unknown", "0", "0", "0"};
    
    printf("test"); //even this does not prijnt for some reason
    
    //reading user filter
    char f_country[40];
    printf("Contry = ");
    if(scanf("%s", f_country)!=1){
        printf("ERROR WRONG TYPE");
        return 0;
    }
    int f_year;
    if(scanf("%s", &f_year)!=1){
        printf("ERROR WRONG TYPE");
        return 0;
    }
    //end of reading users filter
    
    
    //reading intake
    intake_t intake1[INTAKE];
    extract_t extract1[EXTRACT];
    char trash[40];
    
    FILE *filePointer;
    filePointer = fopen("water_intake_stations.txt","w");
    if (filePointer == NULL) 
    {   
         printf("Error! Could not open file\n"); 
         return 0;
    }

    
    for(int i = 0; i < INTAKE; i++){
        printf("Code: ");
        fscanf(filePointer, "s", intake1[i].code);
        fscanf(filePointer, "s", trash);
        fscanf(filePointer, "s", trash);
        printf("Country: ");
        fscanf(filePointer, "s", intake1[i].country);
        printf("Intake type: ");
        fscanf(filePointer, "s", intake1[i].intake_type);
        printf("Water type: ");
        fscanf(filePointer, "s", intake1[i].water_type);
        printf("Purification: ");
        fscanf(filePointer, "s", intake1[i].purification);
    }

    fclose(filePointer);
    //end of reading intake
    
    
    //reading extract
    char trash2[40];
    
    FILE *filePointer2;
    filePointer2 = fopen("water_extraction.txt","w");
    if (filePointer2 == NULL) 
    {   
         printf("Error! Could not open file\n"); 
         return 1;
    }

    
    for(int i = 0; i < EXTRACT; i++){
        printf("Code: ");
        fscanf(filePointer2, "s", extract1[i].code);
        printf("Year: ");
        fscanf(filePointer2, "s", extract1[i].year);
        fscanf(filePointer2, "s", trash2); //do not need that column
        printf("Amount: ");
        fscanf(filePointer2, "s", extract1[i].amount);
    }

    fclose(filePointer2);
    //end of reading extract
    
    //filtering
    char buffer[40];
    int temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6,temp7,temp8,temp9,temp10,temp11,temp12,temp13,temp14,temp15,temp16,temp17,temp18,temp19,temp20,temp21,temp22,temp23,temp24 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < INTAKE; i++){
        
        if(strcmp(intake1[i].country, f_country)==0){
            
            for(int j = 0; j<EXTRACT; j++){
                
                if(strcmp(intake1[i].code, extract1[j].code)==0||f_year==extract1[j].year){
                    
                    if(intake1[i].water_type == 20){
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 30){
                            
                            itoa(temp1 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, unknown[3]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 31){
                            
                            itoa(temp2 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, unknown[1]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 32){
                            
                            itoa(temp3 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, unknown[2]);
                            
                        }
                    }
                    if(intake1[i].water_type == 21){
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 30){
                            
                            itoa(temp4 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, ground[3]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 31){
                            
                            itoa(temp5 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, ground[1]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 32){
                            
                            itoa(temp6 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, ground[2]);
                            
                        }
                    }   
                    if(intake1[i].water_type == 22){
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 30){
                            
                            itoa(temp7 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, surface[3]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 31){
                            
                            itoa(temp8 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, surface[1]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 32){
                            
                            itoa(temp9 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, surface[2]);
                            
                        }
                    }
                    if(intake1[i].water_type == 23){
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 30){
                            
                            itoa(temp10 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, sea[3]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 31){
                            
                            itoa(temp11 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, sea[1]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 32){
                            
                            itoa(temp12 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, sea[2]);
                            
                        }
                    }
                        
                    if(intake1[i].water_type == 24){
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 30){
                            
                            itoa(temp13 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, mineral[3]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 31){
                            
                            itoa(temp14 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, mineral[1]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 32){
                            
                            itoa(temp15 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, mineral[2]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    if(intake1[i].water_type == 25){
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 30){
                            
                            itoa(temp16 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, mining[3]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 31){
                            
                            itoa(temp17 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, mining[1]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 32){
                            
                            itoa(temp18 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, mining[2]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    if(intake1[i].water_type == 26){
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 30){
                            
                            itoa(temp19 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, quarry[3]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 31){
                            
                            itoa(temp20 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, quarry[1]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 32){
                            
                            itoa(temp21 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, quarry[2]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    if(intake1[i].water_type == 26){
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 30){
                            
                            itoa(temp19 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, quarry[3]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 31){
                            
                            itoa(temp20 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, quarry[1]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 32){
                            
                            itoa(temp21 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, quarry[2]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    if(intake1[i].water_type == 27){
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 30){
                            
                            itoa(temp22 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, technical[3]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 31){
                            
                            itoa(temp23 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, technical[1]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        if(intake1[i].purification == 32){
                            
                            itoa(temp24 + extract1[j].amount, buffer, 10);
                            strcpy(buffer, technical[2]);
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
                
            
        
    //filtering end

    //printing start
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%s   ", line1[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%s   ", ground[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%s   ", mineral[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%s   ", mining[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%s   ", quarry[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%s   ", sea[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%s   ", surface[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%s   ", technical[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%s   ", unknown[i]);
    }
    //printing end need to make function out of this
    
            
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stepping this in a *debugger* should prove highly informative. A 400-line code dump with the only hint of what is wrong being, "doesn't do anything" isn't constructive. That said, `if (scanf("%s", &f_year) != 1)` is absolutely wrong. That's an `int` var you're trying to read a *string* into. Similarly, things like `fscanf(filePointer, "s", intake1[i].code);`is nonsense. `s` isn't a format specifier; `%s` is. Turn up your compiler warnings and treat them *all* as errors. There are a LOT of them.

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks! Didn't notice that. The thing is compiler doesn't show up any errors, that's the thing. I simply cannot write anything more constructive than that

Comment: @WhozCraig I use notepad++ +gcc compiler, run my program using console. It usually shows all the errors but not in this case

Comment: Turn up your warnings and treat them as errors (because they *all* are exactly that). acceptable *syntax* does not mean correct code. At best it only means *compilable* code. If you're using `gcc` or `clang` use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` among your compiler flags.

Comment: Don't share pictures of text, share text instead.

Comment: Does it work with smaller files? Note your code has two nested for loops, so it's (basically) a `O(n^2)` algorithm... meaning that if it takes 1 second with 10*10 lines will take 10000 seconds (2.5+ hours) with 1000*1000 lines

Comment: @pmg has a good point, but 1 ms is probably a more realistic timing for 10 * 10 lines. However, you have a lot more than 1000 * 1000 lines. 3,000 * 200,000 lines at this much higher speed would take over 1.5 hours to complete.

Comment: If the two files were sorted, the output can be found in O(n) time. So instead of 1 ms for 10x10 and >1.5 hours for the full files, it would take closer 0.1 ms for 10x10 and under 3 minutes for the whole file.

Comment: You lot are missing the point. Read the comment. She said the compiler is not even showing the most basic scanf error. Show us the gcc command.

Comment: @Humpity , sorry for not answering yesterday, I posted it, screenshot of my console

Comment: It looks like you're using mingw/mysys or cygwin. gcc should at least output an error. Try a simple program with a lot of syntax errors. If you get no output, then gcc is not installed properly.